# How do I desserialize a Path2D.Double object?

Tags: java, deserialization, path-2d

I'm trying to save an object that has an `ArrayList` of `Connector`, which is a class that extends `Path2D.Double`. It gives me the exception `gui.Connector; no valid constructor`. I did a little research and came across this:

[no valid constructor when serializing a subclass of Path2D.Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472508/no-valid-constructor-when-serializing-a-subclass-of-path2d-double/12787960#12787960)

It gave me a fine explanation, but no workaround. Is there a way I can desserialize a subclass of `Path2D.Double`?

Comment: Can you wrap the `Path2D.Double` within the `Connector` class...in other words do you need to use _inheritance_ (eg what behavior do you need to override in the Path2D.Double class)?

Comment: You're right... I did not need to use inheritance in this case. But still, if I wrap it, will it deserialize?

Comment: It worked, @copeg ! Thanks for pointing that out. May you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Path2D.Double` can be serialized/deserialized without issue (it has access to the Path2D no-arg constructor). If you do not need to override the behavior of `Path2D.Double`, you can have an instance of this class as a field in your `Connector` class (rather than have `Connector` extend the `Path2D.Double`).